# Python - Detect inflection point in list and replace

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The title is actually misleading, but I didn't know how to describe my problem in a short sentence. I don't care about inflection point, but I care about the point where the values switch from x > 1 to x < 1.

Consider the following array:

```
a = np.array([0.683, 0.819, 0.678, 1.189, 1.465, 0.93 , 0.903, 1.321, 1.321, 0.785, 0.875])

# do something... and here's what I want:

np.array([True, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, True, True])
```

Here are the rules:

1. First point in array is the starting point, and is always marked True
2. In order for values to be marked `True`, it must be smaller than 1 (x < 1).
3. However, even if a value is smaller than 1, if it's between the first value smaller than 1 and the first value greater than 1, mark it as `False`.

In case my explanation doesn't make sense, here's the picture of what I want to do:

[image]

The decimal values in the array `a` are just ratios: current point / previous point. How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code I put hereafter do what you asked.  Unfortunately, it doesn't use list comprehension.
The first thing I did was to write a function that find the indexes of the first value below zero and the first value above zero.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.683, 0.819, 0.678, 1.189, 1.465, 0.93 , 0.903, 1.321, 1.321, 0.785, 0.875])

### if a number is below ONE but in a position between the first true below zero and the first false above zero
### then it's false

## find the two indexes of the first value below 1 and the first value above 1
def find_indx(a):

    first_min=0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if(a[i]<1):
            first_min=i
            break
    first_max=0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if(a[i]>1):
            first_max=i
            break
    return([first_min,first_max])
```

Using this function you can set, to false, the values that are below zero but are in the interval between the first below zero and the first above zero.
The two indexes are stored in "false_range".

Once you have that it's quite easy. The first point is always true. 
If the indexes are between the "false_range" and below zero they become false.
If the points are outside the "false_range" their value depends if they are above 1 or below.

```
false_range=find_indx(a)

truth_list=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    ## the first value is always true
    if(i==0):
        truth_list.append(True)
    else:
        ## if the index is between the false_range and 
        ## this value is below 1 assign False
        if(i>false_range[0] and i<false_range[1] and a[i]<1):
            truth_list.append(False)
        ## in all the other cases it depends only if the value is below or above zero
        elif(a[i]>1):
            truth_list.append(False)
        elif(a[i]<1):
            truth_list.append(True)


print(truth_list)

[True, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, True, True]
```

The printed list correspond to the one you gave, but please, test this solution before using it.